# What's the best way to scope a session for use with updates and queries

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy and the suggested `with session_scope()` context.

I've just found that using the scope to issue a query causes the resulting object(s) to somehow reattach to the session, perhaps in the `session.commit()` call. I've narrowed it down to this test case, which fails with a `DetachedInstanceError`:

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import sqlalchemy as sql
import sqlalchemy.orm as sqlorm
from contextlib import contextmanager

DeclarativeBase = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class Test(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, sql.Sequence('id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    value = sql.Column(sql.Integer)

engine = sql.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sqlorm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
    session = Session()
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

with session_scope() as session:
    session.add(Test(value=10))

with session_scope() as session:
    items = session.query(Test).all()

print items[0].value
```

I have managed to get it to work by adding a `commit` parameter to `session_scope`, and changing `session.commit()` to `if commit: session.commit()`, but this is kind of ugly and error-prone. It seems like commit should be a no-op if only queries have been executed. Is there a better, standard way to do this?

Comment: The code where you access your ORM object (print items[0].value), should be inside the session_scope() block.

Comment: Yes, that also fixes the problem, but I want to be able to use the object after the session is closed.

Comment: Try `session.expunge(instance)` to remove the instance from session.